# Installing Tata photon+ in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

Hi i am new to use linux, I dont't know how to use commands please explain me how to install tata photon Plus in layman terms .I have tata photon plus and tata photon max.

Answer (score 1):

- Since you have the  tata photon plus then extract the files on your
  local drive and name the folder Tata_Photon_Linux
- Go into the folder and give execute permissions and then run the
  install file as root

  ```
  cd  ~/Desktop/Tata_Photon_Linux
  chmod +x ./install
  sudo ./install
  ```
- You will get confirmation of completion of the installation. When you
  plug in the USB datacard, the Tata Photon+ dashboard will
  automatically popup. You can start connecting to the internet
  directly by clicking the connect button.

[image]

[Source and more information from here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2013/06/how-to-install-tata-photon-mobile.html)